# How set up a route on the server-side LAN gateway on dumb Routers

Tags: router, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN setup to reach internal LAN from Internet. On the LAN machine that I reach from outside I needed to add the following route:

```
sudo ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.193
```

Where 192.168.0.193 is the OpenVPN server.
In order to reach all machines in the LAN I would need to add this in the LAN gateway. However my router/model from the ISP does not seem to have the option to do so. Do you know another option?

here the server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert vpnserver.crt
key vpnserver.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
cipher AES-256-CBC   # AES
cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES
auth SHA512
user openvpn
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Comment: You actually need to set routes on *all* hosts on the path towards the machines in the LAN, starting with the source host (and your description is too incomplete for us to guess which those should be). Also, there are some issues with [subnets behind OpenVPN](http://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/)

Comment: thanks. So I need to add the route on any LAN host, right? I've added the server.conf too.

Comment: Actually I've just found out that adding in the server.conf the line: push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0" is enough to reach the devices on the LAN. Sorry.